# Loading a local image in UIwebview

Tags: ios, ipad, uiwebview, automatic-ref-counting

I have an image (png) in the app document directory, which is a screenshot of a `UIView`. The image will be saved when user clicked a `UIButton`.  I use `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` to inject the image into a div in a `UIWebView`. The problem is when the app loads first, the correct image it added, but in run time the image is not changed, it only shows the image which was in the directory when loading. I tried cleaning the cache and etc but no use.

**note**
 - the webview loads local html files 
 - I use arc

How can I add the correct image from the documentry directory to the webview. ?

**UPDATE**
it works fine on IOS 5.. issue is only on IOS 6..

Comment: Same problem here :/ can we use some method to reload the data of stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i couldn't find the technical issue behind this problem, but i fixed it by giving unique names every time I save the image file.

```
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    int timeInter = [[NSDate date]timeIntervalSince1970];
    [userDefaults setInteger:timeInter forKey:WHEEL_NUMBER];
    NSNumber *newWheelKey = [userDefaults valueForKey:WHEEL_NUMBER];
```

I store the image with `newWheelKey`. delete the image folder when `viewdiddisappear`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that When you save the image in  document directory every time you have to give different-diffrent name and retrive according image.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are giving image path like this `/Users/file/...some other paths../Documents/Images/imag.png`. 
Image path you are giving should be like this in your `HTML` file, because you are trying to load image from your local path. `file:///Users/file/...some other paths../Documents/Images/imag.png`

Comment: In your htmlString the div tag should be like,  `NSString *htmlString = [NSString stringWithFormat@"<div style=\"background:url('file://%@/%@') no-repeat;\"></div>", documentDirectoryPath, filename];`

Comment: i am using <img src = \"file://%@\" height =220 width = 288>. It loads the images at launch, so no issue with the path. I think it is related to cache.. Im removing the cache using         [[NSURLCache sharedURLCache] removeAllCachedResponses] when initialising the view, but no use!!